# 2D array word search puzzle validation

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

For part of a homework assignment, I have a program that asks the user to enter words they would like hidden in a word search puzzle. Afterwards, I then have to run every word through a function that checks if the word can be horizontally inserted into the puzzle. So the function takes the word and tries to start it at a random row and column location and checks to see if the word will fit. A placement is possible if each character of the word either replaces an empty cell or matches an existing character in the cell. If the word can be inserted, insert the word into the puzzle and stop trying to place the word. I must try to insert the word 10 times into the puzzle (with different starting positions) or until the word is inserted. If after 10 attempts have been made, and the word can't be inserted, the function should end with no insertion of the word. Whether or not the word is inserted, the function must return a code indicating a successful or unsuccessful insertion of the specified word into the puzzle.

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

char puzzle[20][20] = {};

int row = 0;

int column = 0;

char word[20][100] = {};

int numword = 0;

for(i = 0;i < numword;i++)
    {
      horizontalinsertion(puzzle,row,column,word);
    }
```

And this is the function that I have written so far:

```
void horizontalinsertion(char puzzle[][20],int row,int col,char word[][100])

{

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

srand(time(NULL));
    while(i < 10)
    {
      for(j = 0;j < row;j++)
      {
        num1 = (rand()% row);
        for(k = 0;k < col;k++)
        {
          num2 = (rand()% col);
          printf("%d\n",num);
          if(num <= strlen(word[j][k]))
          {
            printf("Word was successfully inserted\n");
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            i++;
          }
        }
      }
    }



return;

}
```

The 'puzzle' array is used to print out the grid of the word search and the size is determined by the user with the 'row' and 'column' variables. The 'word' array stores all of the words that the user wants to be placed in the puzzle and the integer 'numword' is used to keep track of the number of words that the user entered. Mostly I just can't seem to figure out how to stop the loop when the appropriate number is generated, the messages don't print out, and also there should only be 10 numbers generated when 11 are being printed out.
I've been trying to figure this out all day so I greatly appreciate anybody that can help me solve this.

Comment: What is the `num` variable in your first `printf`?

Comment: your function `horizontalinsertion` will insert the word in multiple rows, since you break from the column-loop when the word is inserted, should you only insert once, you should replace `break;` with `return;`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is all in a void function, instead of a `break` you can use a `return` to exit the entire function.